# Deriving First Success Expectation with linearity property of expectation?

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

I'm a newbie studying probability.

Let X be random variables distributed as Geometric Distribution:
X ~ Geom(p)

Let Y be random variables distributed as First Success Distribution:
Y ~ FS(p)

I know how to calculate the Geometric expectation:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kq^kp = pq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kq^{k-1} = pq\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} = \frac{p}{q}$$

and the First Success expectation:
$$E(Y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kq^{k-1}p = p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kq^{k-1} = p\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} = \frac{1}{p}$$

But in the book there is another way to derive the formula for the Y.

it says "Since we can write Y ~ FS(p) as Y = X + 1 where X ~ Geom(p), we have $E(Y) = E(X+1)=\frac{q}{p}+1=\frac{1}{p}$"

I know that both method arrive at the same formula but why the second derivation is valid?

is it because of the linearity property of the expectation? such as E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y) and in this case it is E(Y) = E(X+1) = E(X) + E(1) = $\frac{q}{p}+1$ I didn't know that the linearity property also valid for the constant 1 and if it is valid what is the formal calculation of E(1) ?? why E(1) = 1 ???

Can someone also make correction on my E(Y) calculation above because k starts from 1: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kq^{k-1}p $ , does is make difference from the summation of Geometric expectation which starts at k=0 ?

you can answer the question here or at this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059772/deriving-first-success-expectation-with-linearity-property-of-expectation

Comment: Have you tried to write out $E(1)$ (as a weighted sum, in your case), and see what it gives you? What is the probability that 1 wil take the value 1? What is the probability that it will take any other value?

Comment: First of all in both cases isn't p=1-q? Since geometric is time just before first success  and although I don't know the terminology first success distribution I assume it counts 1 more case. A constant is always equal to its expectation.  so E(Y)=E(X+!)= E(X) +1 =q/p +1.  Your derivations of E(X) and E(Y) in terms of the summations don't appear to be right.

Comment: Wikipedia calls both distributions geometric (although they do differ by 1).

Comment: Actually X has E(X)=1/p and Y has E(Y)=q/p.  So we should have E(Y)=1/p +1

Comment: Sorry E(X)=q/p and E(Y)=1/p.  I got confused by wikipedias definitions.